# Using generating function to find number of ways to distribute $r$ items

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Use a generating function to find the number of ways to distribute 40 jelly beans among ten children if three of the children get an even number of jelly beans.

So I believe the generating function to be:
$$
(1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + \ldots)^3(1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \ldots)^7
$$

and by using infinite series:
$$
\frac1{\left(1-x^2\right)^3}\ \frac1{\left(1-x\right)^7}\
$$

...which means I need to find the coefficients that give $x^{40}$, which there are around twenty of (1 * 46C40 + 3C1 * 44C38 + 4C2 * 42C36 + ...)? Is this correct, or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165906/finding-number-of-summands-by-using-generating-function?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Write it as
$\frac1{(1+x)^3(1-x)^{10}}$
and use the generalized binomial theorem
on each term.